# How to compute the diameter of 3D torus interconnect?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, topology, supercomputers

A 3D torus interconnect is a network topology having `p^3` nodes where `p > 2`. A 3D torus is basically a 3D mesh with links connecting nodes on opposite faces (Am I right?).

The bisection width calculated by me comes out to be `2p^2`. However, I am clueless as to how to approach diameter calculation for this. I don't even know where to even begin because I don't understand what purpose the links connecting nodes on opposing faces serve. For those wondering, diameter is the greatest number of hops needed to send a message from one node to another.

[image: 3dtorus]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a 1D torus interconnect, the diameter is `floor(p/2)`.

Thus, for a 3D torus interconnect, the diameter is `floor(p/2) * 3` since the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) should be used for this grid-based interconnect. To visualize that, you can think about a small `4 x 4 x 4` grid and how data packets move through the edges of the grid.